# Convert one row to multiple rows per subject in a data frame by splitting text data in R

Tags: r, text

I have a dataset with a patient identifier and a text field with a summary of medical findings (1 row per patient).  I would like to create a dataset with multiple rows per patients by splitting the text field so that each sentence of the summary falls on a different line.  Subsequently, I would like to text parse each line looking for certain keywords and negation terms.  An example of the structure of the data frame is (the letters represent the sentences):

**ID       Summary**
1   aaaaa. bb. c
2       d. eee. ff. g. h
3       i. j
4       k

I would like to split the text field at the “.” to convert it to:

**ID        Summary**
1       aaaaa
1       bb
1       c
2       d
2       eee
2       ff
2       g
2       h
3       i
3       j
4       k

R code to create the initial data frame:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)  
Summary <- c("aaaaa. bb. c", "d. eee. ff. g. h", "i. j", "k")  

df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, Summary))  
df$ID <- as.numeric(df$ID)  
df$Summary <- as.character(df$Summary)
```

The following previous posting provides a nice solution:
[Breaking up (melting) text data in a column in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668699/breaking-up-melting-text-data-in-a-column-in-r)

I used the following code from that posting which works for this sample dataset:

```
dflong <- by(df, df$ID, FUN = function(x) {  
  sentence = unlist(strsplit(x$Summary, "[.]"))  
  data.frame(ID = x$ID, Summary = sentence)  
  })  
dflong2<- do.call(rbind,dflong)
```

However, when I try to apply to my larger dataset (>200,000 rows), I get the error message:
Error in data.frame(ID = x$ID, Summary = sentence) :  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

I reduced the data frame down to test it on a smaller dataset and I still get this error message any time the number of rows is >57.

Is there another approach to take that can handle a larger number of rows?  Any advice is appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: There was an almost identical question posted yesterday. Haven't found the post yet but this looks pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668699/breaking-up-melting-text-data-in-a-column-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)

dt[, strsplit(Summary, ". ", fixed = T), by = ID]
#    ID    V1
# 1:  1 aaaaa
# 2:  1    bb
# 3:  1     c
# 4:  2     d
# 5:  2   eee
# 6:  2    ff
# 7:  2     g
# 8:  2     h
# 9:  3     i
#10:  3     j
#11:  4     k
```

There are many ways to address @agstudy's comment about empty `Summary`, but here's a fun one:

```
dt[, c(tmp = "", # doesn't matter what you put here, will delete in a sec
                 # the point of having this is to force the size of the output table
                 # which data.table will kindly fill with NA's for us
       Summary = strsplit(Summary, ". ", fixed = T)), by = ID][,
       tmp := NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because for some rows you have no data ( summary column). Try this should work for you:

```
   dflong <- by(df, df$ID, FUN = function(x) {  
      sentence = unlist(strsplit(x$Summary, "[.]"))  
      ## I just added this line to your solution
      if(length(sentence )==0)
           sentence <- NA
      data.frame(ID = x$ID, Summary = sentence)  
    })  
   dflong2<- do.call(rbind,dflong)
```

PS : This is slightly different from the `data.table` solution which will remove rows where summary equal to ''(0 charcaters). That's said I would would use a data.table solution here since you have more than 200 000 rows.

Comment: I get a different result running this - it only has the first element of the split

Comment: for me as well, it seems to truncate everything beyond the first ".".  however, you brought up a good point about the empty data and why I was getting the error. the data.table solution worked nicely.  thanks.

Comment: @SteveB  I edit my answer. It should be `if` and  `else` and not `ifelse`.