# Convert sentences to words in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in the form of columns - 
input

```
Id  Comment
xc545   Ronald is a great person 
g6548   Hero worship is bad
```

I need the output in the form of 
Result

```
Id  Words 
xc545   Ronald
xc545   is
xc545   a
xc545   great
xc545   person
g6548   Hero
g6548   worship
g6548   is
g6548   bad
```

Need a R statement to execute this.

Following is what I tried -

```
result<-lapply(input,function(x)strsplit(x[2]," "))
```

However this returns only one record.

Comment: May I ask why you want this?  That may determine if a dataframe is the best structure for your data.

Comment: I wanted to search across the sentence for productnames and tag them. I have the productnames(200,000) in another table column. SQL comparison is taking very long.

Answer (score 9):

Suppose `DF` is your data.frame, a possibility could be:

```
> List <- strsplit(DF$Comment, " ")
> data.frame(Id=rep(DF$Id, sapply(List, length)), Words=unlist(List))
     Id   Words
1 xc545  Ronald
2 xc545      is
3 xc545       a
4 xc545   great
5 xc545  person
6 g6548    Hero
7 g6548 worship
8 g6548      is
9 g6548     bad
```

Note that my answer is only valid when there is a simple space between each pair of words.

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` solution inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862875/convert-one-row-to-multiple-rows-per-subject-in-a-data-frame-by-splitting-text-d/16863204#16863204) one:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(df)
dt[,c(Words=strsplit(Comment, " ", fixed = TRUE)), by = Id]
Id      V1
1: xc545  Ronald
2: xc545      is
3: xc545       a
4: xc545   great
5: xc545  person
6: g6548    Hero
7: g6548 worship
8: g6548      is
9: g6548     bad
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `scan`, `tapply` and `stack`:

```
d <- read.table(text='Id  Comment
xc545   "Ronald is a great person"
g6548   "Hero worship is bad"', header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)

stack(tapply(d$Comment, d$Id, function(x) scan(text=x, what='')))
#    values   ind
# 1    Hero g6548
# 2 worship g6548
# 3      is g6548
# 4     bad g6548
# 5  Ronald xc545
# 6      is xc545
# 7       a xc545
# 8   great xc545
# 9  person xc545
```